# The script for connecting a remote network folder gives an error: access denied

Tags: windows, powershell

I wrote a PS script that remotely connects to a network folder using domain administrator credentials to connect. But when executing, an error appears: access is denied. I don't quite understand what the problem is. PS script I run as an administrator, I use the domain administrator credentials in the script. Has anyone encountered anything like this?

```
# The computer name to which you want to connect
$ComputerName = "target_computer_name"

# Domain user credentials (in "domain\username" format)
$Username = "domain\username"
$Password = "password"

# Convert the password to a secure string
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force

# Create a PSCredential object
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePassword

# Network folder to connect to (e.g., "\\file_server\shared_folder")
$SharePath = "\\file_server\shared_folder"

# Drive letter for the network drive (e.g., "Z")
$DriveName = "Z"

# Execute the script on the target computer
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {
    param($SharePath, $DriveName)

    # Check if the network drive with the specified name already exists
    if (-not (Get-PSDrive -Name $DriveName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        # Create the network drive
        New-PSDrive -Name $DriveName -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $SharePath -Persist

        Write-Host "Network drive $DriveName successfully connected to $SharePath"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Network drive with the name $DriveName already exists"
    }
} -ArgumentList $SharePath, $DriveName
```

Answer (score 0):

`New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential` expects a SecureString as password.
[Read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential.-ctor?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-pscredential-ctor(system-management-automation-psobject))

If that doesn't help please show the exact error message, then I can follow up on your issue.

Also you shouldn't write a password in plain text, use something like SecretManagement instead:

```
#Prerequisites
    Set-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' -InstallationPolicy Trusted
    Install-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement -Confirm:$false -Scope AllUsers
    Install-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore -Confirm:$false -Scope AllUsers
    
    Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement
    Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore


#Register a local SecretVault
 Register-SecretVault -Name VaultName -ModuleName 
 Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore -Description "My first secret vault"

# Create a credential object.
$credential = Get-Credential
# Create a new secret named Secret1
Set-Secret -Name Secret1 -Secret $credential

#Creates an encrypted XML to save the vault password locally
Get-Credential | Export-CliXml ~/vaultpassword.xml

#Abstracts the vault password from the created xml
$vaultpassword = (Import-CliXml ~/vaultpassword.xml).Password

#Unlocks the Secretstore to obtain the saved secrets (your admin password)
Unlock-SecretStore -Password $vaultpassword
```

Following piece of script is my version of passing down credentials with SecretManagement:

```
$vaultName = "YourVaultName"
$secretName = "administrator"
$vaultpassword = (Import-CliXml C:\Users\yourname\temp1.xml).Password
Unlock-SecretStore -Password $vaultpassword

$username = "administrator"
$password = Get-Secret -Vault $vaultname -Name $secretName
$psCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)
$TargetServer = 'your server' #could also be an array of servers

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TargetServer -Credential $psCredential -Scriptblock {Your script}
```

For help with SecretManagement I would suggest you looking into [this](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-encrypt-password/) blogpost, thats what teached me the concept

Comment: I apologize for the late response to your comment. I have adjusted the code according to your recommendations, but I still receive the same error:

Access denied
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Z:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
    + PSComputerName        : computername.mydomain.com